# Does SELECT * really take more time than selecting only the needed columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select

Will it make a discernible difference in the time a website page loads? On average, my tables have 10 columns, if I just need 3 of those columns, should I just call those in the query to make it faster?

Comment: what have you seen from your benchmarks?

Comment: The time difference is probably small, and likely swamped by other factors so probably not noticeable alone by the user (but it might add up with multiple users and become critical). Major exception might be if you return a large column of unneeded data (say images stored in a field). However debugging, maintenance and reliability are probably far better reasons to avoid using SELECT *.

Comment: 0.723 sec vs 0.0717 sec for a table where I summed up three columns with 131,563 rows of data. Isn't that no difference at all?

Comment: That is a 10 fold difference in time which is a lot more than I would expect normally. But as others have pointed out below it will depend on the exact conditions. If you were retrieving from a remote server and had (say) several TEXT columns being returned which you did not need the values from then the time difference could be large.

Answer (score 11):

Will it make a *discernable* difference.  Probably not under most circumstances.  Here are some cases where it would possibly make a big difference:

- The 7 unneeded columns are really, really big.
- You are returning lots and lots of rows.
- You have a big table, are getting many rows, and an index is available on the 3 columns but not the 10.

But, there are other reasons not to use `*`:

- It will replace the columns based on the order of the columns in the database at the time the query is compiled.  This can cause problems if the structure of the table changes.
- If a column name changes or is removed, your query would work and subsequent code might break.  If you explicitly list the columns, then the query will break, making the problem easier to spot.
- Typing three column names shouldn't be a big deal.  Explicitly listing the columns makes the code more informative.

Comment: Good point on the ordering and the surprise code breaking. This is also a problem if you're are accessing data in a non-associative array like `$row[0]` in say PHP--code might not break, but you might get unexpected resutls.  Imagine table {name, credit_card_number, email}  is being queried to display the users email address, and someone adds a column after `name`, now `echo $row[2]`  shows credit card number

Answer (score 3):

Yes if you only need a handful of columns, only select those.  Below are some reasons:

1. **THE MOST OBVIOUS:** Extra data needs to be sent back making for larger packets to transmit (or pipe via local socket).  This will increase overall latency.  This might not seem like much for 1 or 2 rows, but wait until you've got 100 or 1000 rows...  7 extra columns of data will significanly affect overall transit latency expecially if you end up having the result set having to be broken into more TCP packets for transmit.  This might not be such an issue if you're hitting a localhost socket, but move your DB to a server across a network, to another datacenter, etc... and the impact will be plain as day!
2. With the MySQL query cache enabled, storing unneeded data in result sets will increase your over cache space needs--larger query caches can suffer performance hits.
3. **A HUGE HIT CAN BE:** If you need only columns that are part of a covering index, doing a `select *` will require follow up  point lookups for the remaining data fields in the main table rather than just use the data from the index table.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you had a table with 1000 columns, and you only needed 3.

What do you think would run faster and why?

This: `SELECT * FROM table_name;`

or this:`SELECT col1, col2, col3, FROM table_name;`

When you are using `*` you are now holding that entire selection (big or small) in memory. The bigger the selection...the more memory its going to use/need.

So even though your table isn't necessarily big, I would still only select the data that you actually need. You might not even notice a difference in speed, but it will definately be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should.

Using named columns in select is a best practice working with database for multiple reasons.

Only the needed data travel from the database to the application server reducing cpu, memory and disk usage.

It helps detecting coding errors and structure changes.

There are only a few cases when using select * is a good idea, in all the other queries do yourself a favour and use the column names.

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely. * will get replaced with all the column names. After that only the execution starts. For example if there are 3 columns a, b, c in a table.. select a, b, c directly starts execution where as select * starts  transforming the query into select a, b, c after that only the execution stats.

Answer (score 0):

The short of it is yes, if you are returning more data it will take longer. This may be a very very very tiny amount of time but yes it will take longer. As stated above select * can be dangerous in a production situation where you may not be the one designing/implementing the database. If you assume that columns are returned in a particular order or the database structure is of a particular type and then the DBA goes in and makes some kind of a change and does not inform you, you may have an issue with your code.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is very minimal, but there is a slight difference, I think it really depends on several factors for which is faster.

**1)** How many columns are in the table?

**2)** How many columns do you actually need to grab?

**3)** How many records are you grabbing?

In your case, based on what you said of having 10 columns and only needing 3 of those columns, I doubt it'll make a difference if you use `'Select *'` or not, unless perhaps you're grabbing tens of thousands of records. But in more extreme cases with a lot more columns involved I have found `'Select *'` to be slightly faster, but that might not be true in all cases.

I once did some speed tests in a SQLite table with over 150 columns, where I needed to grab only about 40 of the columns, and I needed all 20,000+ records. The speed differences were very minimal (we're talking 20 to 40 milliseconds difference), but it was actually faster to grab the data from All the columns with a `'SELECT ALL *'`, rather than going `'Select All Field1, Field2, etc'`.

I assume the more records and columns in your table, the greater the speed difference this example will net you. But if you only needed 3 columns in a gigantic table I'd guess that just grabbing those 3 columns would be faster.

Bottom line though, if you really care about the minimal speed differences between `'Select *'` and `'Select field1, field2, etc'`, then do some speed tests.